# Change available select box options based on selected filters [Jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this isn't best solution and loading sermons dynamically through SQL statements would be better but I have a Sermons page on http://www.ypc.org.au/resources/sermons/all#list

I have a Filter Section that allows you to filter sermons by book(series), preachers and year.

Currently all sermons are loaded on page load. Some sermons are then hidden based on what filters are selected through the below Jquery script.

This works perfectly hiding any sermons that are not meant to be shown for the selected filters.

The issue is I would like to hide available select options that are not apart of the selected filter options.

For example: Preacher Al Burke has not preached in the James Series, so when I change the series filter to James, his name should also dissapear as a selectable option from the Preacher select box. Otherwise selecting both James series and Al Burke Preacher will show no sermons as he has not preached in that series.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#series, #preacher").change(function() {

    var series = $("#series").val(); //Series user has selected.
    var preacher = $("#preacher").val(); //Preacher user has selected.
    $(".wrapper").hide();

    if (series == "all") {
      if (preacher == "all") {
        $(".wrapper").show(); // Show All Sermons
      } else { //Series == All AND Preacher != All
        $(".wrapper").each(function() {
          if ($(this).hasClass(preacher)) {
            $(this).show(); //Show Sermons from selected preacher
          }

        });
      }

    } else { //Series != ALL
      if (preacher == "all") {

        $(".wrapper").each(function() {
          if ($(this).hasClass(series)) {
            $(this).show(); //Show Sermons from selected series
          }

        });

      } else {
        $(".wrapper").each(function() {
          if ($(this).hasClass(series) && $(this).hasClass(preacher)) {
            $(this).show(); //Show Sermons from selected series & preacher.
          }

        });
      }
    }



  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper james peter_gimbert"> class="wrapper james peter_gimbert" </div>
<div class="wrapper james adrian_armstrong"> class="wrapper james adrian_armstrong" </div>
<div class="wrapper galatians al_burke"> class="wrapper galatians al_burke" </div>
<div class="wrapper galatians adrian_armstrong"> class="wrapper galatians adrian_armstrong" </div>
<div class="wrapper galatians al_burke"> class="wrapper galatians al_burke" </div>
<div class="wrapper galatians peter_gimbert"> class="wrapper galatians peter_gimbert" </div>
<div class="wrapper galatians al_burke"> class="wrapper galatians al_burke" </div>
<div class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke"> class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke" </div>
<div class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke"> class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke" </div>
<div class="wrapper 1_samuel adrian_armstrong"> class="wrapper 1_samuel adrian_armstrong" </div>
<div class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke"> class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke" </div>
<div class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke"> class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke" </div>
<div class="wrapper 1_samuel adrian_armstrong"> class="wrapper 1_samuel adrian_armstrong" </div>
<div class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke"> class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke" </div>
<div class="wrapper philippians adrian_armstrong"> class="wrapper philippians adrian_armstrong" </div>
<div class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke"> class="wrapper 1_samuel al_burke" </div>
<div class="wrapper psalms al_burke"> class="wrapper psalms al_burke" </div>
<div class="wrapper psalms al_burke"> class="wrapper psalms al_burke" </div>


<select id="series">
            <option value="all">All Books</option>
            <option value="james">James</option>
            <option value="galatians">Galatians</option>
            <option value="philippians">Philippians</option>
            <option value="1_samuel">1 Samuel</option>
    </select>

<select id="preacher">
            <option value="all">All Preachers</option>
            <option value="al_burke">Al Burke</option>
            <option value="peter_gimbert">Peter Gimbert</option>
            <option value="adrian_armstrong">Adrian Armstrong</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Share your `html` and provide a working snippet

Comment: Please share your complete code instead of Images

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Sorry full code now provided.. hopefully that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for sharing complete code,

I saw that your select box value is directly related to your wrappers.

Try following code.

```
    var r = "";
    var v ="";
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#series").change(function(){
            v = $(this).val(); 
            r = /(v)/;
            if(v == "all"){
                $("#preacher").children().show();
                return;
            }
            $("#preacher option").hide();
//This line removed

            $(".wrapper").each(function(k1,v1){
                if($(v1).attr("class").search(" "+v+" ")<0){
                    $(v1).hide();
                }else{
                    $(v1).show();
                    $("#preacher").children("option[value^=" + $(v1).attr("class").split(" ")[2] + "]").show()
                }
            });
             $("#preacher").children("option[value^=all]").show(); // Line Added
        });

    });
```

I hope this will solve your problem of Showing and hiding value in dropdown

Comment: Thanks Alpesh! Works great! However one issue I noticed is that when you select a series or a preacher, the All Preachers Or All Series option dissapears. Is there a way to always show this no matter what options are selected?

Comment: @masterg174, I made change in above code, try new one

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much! Working great.

Sorry one more thing. Would it also be possible to do this in the reverse for preachers. E.g. If I select Al Burke first from preachers dropdown, could it remove the option James for instance from series as there is no wrapper class with both james and al_burke in it. No big deal if it's difficult to do - I can see at the moment it simply reverts to all preachers if Al Burke is first selected and then James.

Comment: Actually it is working fine already as the results change when you change the series anyway. Seems to be working fine. Thanks for all your help!